# How to get a jsp file to work as a welcome file on websphere 8?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, websphere

I am trying to use a .jsp file as the welcome file in a basically straightforward jsp app in Websphere8. The aim is to get the following to work:

```
(a) http://something.com/base/?a=b&c=d
```

just like

```
(b) http://something.com/base/thepage.jsp?a=b&c=d
```

In the dev enironment, this works by just adding the following to web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>thepage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

A difference is that in dev, in ibm-web-ext-xmi we have

```
fileServingEnabled="true"
```

whereas it is set to false in production (the web server handles file serving, and it works). Url (b) works in production, but (a) doesn't.

The question is: how to solve this? Is there any properties I need to set? Any other ideas?

Thanks!
Håkan

Comment: Uh, just disable file serving?

Comment: Well, yes, disable file serving appears to have that affect, but it must be the webserver serving static content, not the application server. That's a given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following solves the problem:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>jsp/welcome.jsp</jsp-file> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

A servlet mapping from the root to the jsp file.